# Keep getting an error when trying to run post to api with futter spinkit

Tags: flutter, api, dart

[image: Spinkit immage]

Hi all

Anyone had this error before - cant run my application and its driving me mad!!

Tried removing and installing again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formatting error in your pubspec.yaml file.

The error is in this line

```
provider:
```

This line is incomplete, as it is missing a version constraint after the ":".  You should specify a version constraint for the provider package or remove it entirely.

So e.g. change it to

```
provider: 6.0.4
```